# In-app UPDATES - startUpdateFlowForResult not triggering the update dialog

Tags: android, in-app-update

I am using fakeUpdateManager to test in-app update dialog, i have set updateAvailable to 10- 10 is the version code i have on playstore and i am building the build in app(Release) with version code 9.

The app is in internal testing on store.

fakeUpdateManager = FakeAppUpdateManager(this)
        fakeUpdateManager?.setUpdateAvailable(10)

```
    // Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
    fakeUpdateManager?.registerListener(installStateUpdatedListener)
    fakeUpdateManager
        ?.appUpdateInfo
        ?.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
            Log.i("MainActivity", "${fakeUpdateManager?.isImmediateFlowVisible} appUpdateInfo : $appUpdateInfo")


            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE || appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability()
                == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS
                // For a flexible update, use AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE
                && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
            ) {
                // Request the update.
                fakeUpdateManager?.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                    // Pass the intent that is returned by 'getAppUpdateInfo()'.
                    appUpdateInfo,
                    // Or 'AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE' for flexible updates.
                    AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                    // The current activity making the update request.
                    this,
                    // Include a request code to later monitor this update request.
                    APP_UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE
                )
            } else if (appUpdateInfo.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED) {
                // After the update is downloaded, show a notification
                // and request user confirmation to restart the app.
                popupSnackbarForCompleteUpdate()
            }

        }
```

Following code is for listening to download completion etc, but it is of no use as the updateFlow is not even starting :

```
 var installStateUpdatedListener: InstallStateUpdatedListener =
    object : InstallStateUpdatedListener {
        override fun onStateUpdate(state: InstallState) {
            if (state.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED) {
                popupSnackbarForCompleteUpdate()
            } else if (state.installStatus() == InstallStatus.INSTALLED) {
                if (fakeUpdateManager != null) {
                    fakeUpdateManager?.unregisterListener(this)
                }
            } else {
                Log.i(
                    "MainActivity",
                    "InstallStateUpdatedListener: state: " + state.installStatus()
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

inside appUpdateInfo - getting the following value

```
appUpdateInfo : AppUpdateInfo{packageName=com.property.ility, availableVersionCode=10, updateAvailability=2, installStatus=0, clientVersionStalenessDays=-1, bytesDownloaded=0, totalBytesToDownload=0, immediateUpdateIntent=PendingIntent{3f8812d: android.os.BinderProxy@df8e662}, flexibleUpdateIntent=PendingIntent{af823f3: android.os.BinderProxy@df8e662}}
```

i checked - `fakeUpdateManager?.isImmediateFlowVisible`  it returns me `false`

and below is the method provided by FakeUpdateManagerClass . The docs says :

```
/**
 * Returns whether the user confirmation screen of the immediate update is visible to 
the user.
 */

public boolean isImmediateFlowVisible() { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?  I just had integrate google in app update in my project and flow the testing steps provided by google blog but update dialog is not appearing..even i have try to add Logs but nothing will happen in the code...can you please help me to find out the issue

Comment: actually the update dialog pop started showing up automatically the next day, i didnt make any change in code.